# Detecting compiler configuration in cmake file

Tags: c++, cmake

Either this is really easy and I'm just not able to find the correct way to do it, or I've wildly misunderstood something. I'm attempting to add a conditional to a CMakeLists.txt file to include the proper .lib file depending on which build configuration type is being used (within visual studio at the moment). So for example, if configuration in visual studio is set to `Debug` then use file `zlibstaticd.lib` vs `zlibstatic.lib`. Below is what I have that's not working:

```
add_library(ZLIB_LIBRARY OBJECT IMPORTED)
# zlib added via assimp, and I can't get CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX value to overwrite (because it's set within zlibs cmake file when using MSVC)
# so we have to do this check

if($<CONFIG:Debug>)
    set_target_properties(ZLIB_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/zlibstaticd.lib)
else()
    set_target_properties(ZLIB_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/zlibstatic.lib)
endif()
```

I've also tried `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` but it's always an empty string. Below is my entire `CMakeLists.txt` file so you can see what it is I'm doing (building a singular static library which contains many other static libraries):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)


# Define our project name
set(PROJECT_NAME myProjectName)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})


# Make sure binary directory is not the same as source directory
if(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL PROJECT_BINARY_DIR)
  message(
    FATAL_ERROR
      "In-source builds not allowed. Please make a new directory (called a build directory) and run CMake from there."
  )
endif()


# This Project Depends on External Project(s) 
include(ExternalProject)


set(libGLFW glfw)
ExternalProject_Add(${libGLFW}
PREFIX          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLFW}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
GIT_TAG         3.3.4
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLFW}/install
                -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF
                -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
                -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
)

set(libGLAD glad)
ExternalProject_Add(${libGLAD}
PREFIX          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLAD}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad.git
GIT_TAG         origin/master
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLAD}/install
                -DGLAD_INSTALL:BOOL=ON
                -DGLAD_PROFILE:STRING="core"
                -DGLAD_ALL_EXTENSIONS:BOOL=ON
                -DUSE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL:BOOL=OFF
)

set(libGLM glm)
ExternalProject_Add(${libGLM}
PREFIX          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLM}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/g-truc/glm.git
GIT_TAG         origin/master
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLM}/install
                -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF
                -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS:BOOL=OFF
                -DGLM_TEST_ENABLE:BOOL=OFF
)



set(libAssimp assimp)
ExternalProject_Add(${libAssimp}
PREFIX          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libAssimp}
GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/assimp/assimp.git
GIT_TAG         v5.0.1
GIT_SHALLOW     ON
CMAKE_ARGS      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libAssimp}/install
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_ALL_IMPORTERS_BY_DEFAULT:BOOL=OFF
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_ALL_EXPORTERS_BY_DEFAULT:BOOL=OFF
                -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS:BOOL=OFF
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_FBX_IMPORTER:BOOL=ON
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_OBJ_IMPORTER:BOOL=ON
                -DASSIMP_BUILD_OBJ_EXPORTER:BOOL=ON
                -DASSIMP_LIBRARY_SUFFIX:STRING=
                -DLIBRARY_SUFFIX:STRING=
                -DCMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX:STRING=
                -DASSIMP_INJECT_DEBUG_POSTFIX:BOOL=OFF
)

# Note set_target_properties will need conditionals for windows/linux since extensions differ

# Create the oject files we will join together to create our singular static library, using the projects
# that were previously added above via ExternalProject_Add
# INSTALL_DIR not being set to value of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, so manuallysetting
#ExternalProject_Get_Property(${libGLFW} INSTALL_DIR)

# SETUP GLFW
set(GLFW_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLFW}/install)
add_library(GLFW_LIBRARY OBJECT IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(GLFW_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/glfw3.lib)

# SETUP GLAD
set(GLAD_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLAD}/install)
add_library(GLAD_LIBRARY OBJECT IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(GLAD_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/glad.lib)

# SETUP GLM
# GLM is header only library, so we simply include it's include directory in target_include_directories below
set(GLM_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libGLM}/install)

# SETUP ASSIMP and it's dependencies
set(ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dep/${libAssimp}/install)
add_library(ASSIMP_LIBRARY OBJECT IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(ASSIMP_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/assimp.lib)

add_library(IRRXML_LIBRARY OBJECT IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(IRRXML_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/IrrXML.lib)

add_library(ZLIB_LIBRARY OBJECT IMPORTED)
# zlib added via assimp, and I can't get CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX value to overwrite (because it's set within zlibs cmake file when using MSVC)
# so we have to do this check

if($<CONFIG:Debug>)
    set_target_properties(ZLIB_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/zlibstaticd.lib)
else()
    set_target_properties(ZLIB_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/zlibstatic.lib)
endif()




# Documentation states not to do this, but do it anyway for the time being since it prevents us from having
# to manually list all project files
file(GLOB_RECURSE headers CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")


# Create a single .lib file containing our compiled objects, and the compiled objects of all other dependencies
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${headers} ${sources} 
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:GLFW_LIBRARY> 
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:GLAD_LIBRARY>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ASSIMP_LIBRARY>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:IRRXML_LIBRARY>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ZLIB_LIBRARY>
)


# Add all include file paths
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
    PUBLIC ${GLFW_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLAD_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${GLM_INSTALL_DIR}/include
    PUBLIC ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/include
)


# Specify the order in which libs depend on each other, use the name of the ExternalProject, not the name of the
# library object you create and use with add_library
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libGLFW} ${libGLAD} ${libGLM} ${libAssimp})
```

Comment: Let's take this one item at a time. For the first part of the issue, you can try doing it this way set_target_properties(volume PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "d"). So you don't need the conditional on <CONFIG:Debug>

Comment: Additionally, if that does not work, you can use the IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG and IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE property to set your debug and release libraries.

Comment: Regarding your second query, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE  is only set for Linux systems. The equivalent for VS generators is CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES

Comment: Since zlib is imported and built as a dependency of assimp, and I'm adding assimp via ExternalProject_Add...I'm not sure how I would go about using `set_target_properties(volume PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")` to set the property in zlib before it's built. Looking into IMPORTED_LOCATION.

Comment: Sorry I had the wrong instruction there, forgot to update it :) set_target_properties(ZLIB_LIBRARY PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")

Comment: Setting `DEBUG_POSTFIX` on an imported target does nothing. It controls the name when the target is _built_, which imported targets never are.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but I love your Ziltoid avatar \m/

Comment: @AlexReinking Then bring me your universe's ultimate cup of coffee....BLACK....Make it perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> add_library(ZLIB_LIBRARY OBJECT IMPORTED)
> # zlib added via assimp, and I can't get CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX value to overwrite (because it's set within zlibs cmake file when using MSVC)
> # so we have to do this check
>
> if($<CONFIG:Debug>)
>     set_target_properties(ZLIB_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/zlibstaticd.lib)
> else()
>     set_target_properties(ZLIB_LIBRARY PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS ${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/zlibstatic.lib)
> endif()
> ```

Generator expressions are evaluated *after* the configuration step has run, so they're just literal strings when the `if()` statement sees them. Basically, the CMake configure step is *meta-programming* a declarative language of targets and generator expressions that gets *compiled* into Ninja build files (or whatever) by the generator.

You can set the library up as follows:

```
add_library(zlib OBJECT IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
  zlib
  PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_OBJECTS_RELEASE "${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/zlibstatic.lib"
    IMPORTED_OBJECTS_DEBUG "${ASSIMP_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/zlibstaticd.lib"
)
```

CMake first tries `IMPORTED_OBJECTS_$<CONFIG>` before trying `IMPORTED_OBJECTS` when resolving a library path.

---

All that said, I have to wonder why you don't just use `find_package`, vcpkg, Conan, or maybe `add_subdirectory` / `FetchContent` to manage your dependencies. **This seems like a lot of pain** given that all of those libraries (I think) either provide their own `find_package` config packages or CMake provides a find module for them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What I'm doing that might be a little odd (why I'm treating those .libs as objects) is because my root level project is a static library, and I'm injecting all of the dependency .libs into the final myproject.lib so that down the road it can be distributed without the user needing to locate and compile it's dependencies...a singular self contained static library. I stumbled across [this post](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/16931) where this method was offered as a solution, however if there is a better one I'm all ears (new to cmake).

Comment: What you propose works perfectly, I only needed to substitute `IMPORTED_LOCATION_*` for `IMPORTED_OBJECTS_*`

Comment: @whitwhoa - ah, I've never seen that Windows-specific hack before... I'll edit my answer to leave that untouched

Comment: When you say Windows-specific hack...is there something about this method that I'm going to run into issues with on linux? I know I'll have to check for OS and swap file extensions, but apart from that...?

Comment: @whitwhoa - The `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:...>` thing won't work on macOS or Linux because that's not how the archiver works in general. Brad King has a comment about that in the issue you linked.

Comment: Generally, if you want to bundle static dependencies, I would suggest using the platform-specific archive tool (like `lib.exe` or `ar`) to merge the libraries in a `POST_BUILD` custom command and use `target_link_libraries` with `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>` so that your exported targets "forget" about the dependencies.

Comment: THANK YOU! That last comment really helped fill in some gaps for me! I'll probably wind up researching that and re-working this whole cmake file now :D. I've been working on this project on windows for the last 3 years and just always relied on compiling the .lib files into my .lib file. I was unaware of lib.exe.

Comment: @whitwhoa - Best of luck! Glad I could help. :)